# grid-area not working for 1 row after build create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, css-grid, netlify

`grid-area` not working for 1 row after building `create-react-app`
The post is awaiting moderator approval.
This post is currently awaiting approval by the moderators of r/css before it can appear in the subreddit.
it is an 8x8 grid for a checkers app and row E is being shoved out of the grid after building `create-react-app`

This is row E all in one square:
[image]

and it added an extra row and column to put the row there:
[image]

This is the output of the build on netlify:

```
[data-grid=e1], [data-grid=e3], [data-grid=e5], [data-grid=e7] {
    grid-area: NaN
}
```

my board css:

```
.board, .board2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20vw;
    top: 5vh;
    width: 45vw;
    height: 45vw;
    display: grid;
    grid: [rowA-start] "A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6 A7 A8" 12.5% [rowA-end]
          [rowB-start] "B1 B2 B3 B4 B5 B6 B7 B8" 12.5% [rowB-end]
          [rowC-start] "C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8" 12.5% [rowC-end]
          [rowD-start] "D1 D2 D3 D4 D5 D6 D7 D8" 12.5% [rowD-end]
          [rowE-start] "e1 e2 e3 e4 e5 e6 e7 e8" 12.5% [rowE-end]
          [rowF-start] "F1 F2 F3 F4 F5 F6 F7 F8" 12.5% [rowF-end]
          [rowG-start] "G1 G2 G3 G4 G5 G6 G7 G8" 12.5% [rowG-end]
          [rowH-start] "H1 H2 H3 H4 H5 H6 H7 H8" 12.5% [rowH-end]
          / 12.5% 12.5% 12.5% 12.5% 12.5% 12.5% 12.5% 12.5%
}
```

any help would be appreciated Thanks

Project Link: https://mern-checkers.netlify.app/checkers/sdf

GitHub Link: https://github.com/ziphtheur/CheckersApp/tree/main/client/src/components

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by changing out the E1-E8 row and setting it to Z1-Z8 but I don't know why that worked. oh well